# Drupal .dev database problem

Tags: database

Drupal website unexpectingly takes all data from .dev db, thow settings point the main db.

Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: check settings.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your settings are messed up somehow. I'd suggest looking into the [multi-site](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site) capability to keep things straight.

You would create directories for live and test under `/sites`. Assuming `example.com` and `test.example.com` are your site:

```
/sites
    /example.com
        settings.php    # connection details for your live database

    /test.example.com
        settings.php    # connection details for your test database

    /example.local
        settings.php    # (optional) details for local development environment
```

Under this scheme, when you browse http://example.com, Drupal will look for the database settings in `/sites/example.com/settings.php`. When you browse http://test.example.com, Drupal will look in `/sites/test.example.com/settings.php` and so on.

An alternative would be to use environment variables set in you Apache or Nginx configuration. You would then use the PHP [getenv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getenv.php) function to access the values. This approach would be a little bit harder to set up and troubleshoot.